# How to make join of three tables to retrieve record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

In rails project

I have **tables**

```
   device(device_id ,name , srn)

   start(start_id, device_id,starttime)

   stop(stop_id ,device_id,stoptime)
```

I want to display : **device_id, name ,srn ,starttime ,stoptime** from above tables

**As one device starts and stops many times the data is stored in tables with that device_id.**

i am using

```
@data=Device.select('device_id,srn,name,starttime,stoptime').joins(:start, :stop)
```

but **my problem**is that

- It generates **duplicate rows** as only device_id is compared by query
- If for device_id=1 I have two **starts in start table** and  **two stops in stop table**
  it shows four rows in the result .

**I want only two.**  eliminating duplicate ..

Plz help me.